# Cost of catching SIGSEGV in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, segmentation-fault

I am trying to optimize somebody else's program for a compilers project and I had a couple of questions.

This program sets a block of memory to read-only and then writes to it based on previously unknown input. Then it catches the SIGSEGV that gets called, stores the page address, and then makes the memory page write-enabled. This way it can keep track of which pages were "dirtied". This allows the program to avoid storing gigabytes of unecessary space.

My main question is what kind of hit causing and then catching a SIGSEGV costs the performance? This will really help me determine whether some of my ideas for changing the program will help, or if they will actually make things worse.

Ideally I will be able to avoid using the SIGSEGV method by using clever compilation techniques, but I want to determine how inefficient the current method is first.

Thanks!

Comment: Or you could let the operating system do *precisely that operation*. It's called "[memory mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)."

Answer (score 2):

It's quite likely that handling occasional page faults is significantly more efficient than the "clever compilation techniques" that you have in mind, whatever those techniques might be.

Of course the only way to be sure is to measure both.

P.S. For some numbers, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10227511/367273